# restore the angular project from the dist folder

Tags: angular, typescript, web, deployment, hosting

i have to update a website builded by angular , in the server i found the dist folder ,
but i can't update the main.js file ,
is there any solution to get the files of the angular project  from the dist folder ?
this what in the server :
[image]

i want to get the files of the angular project from this dist folder to make the modifications
cause i don't have the angular project

Comment: You need to get the source code, that can't necessarily be recreated from the build outputs.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. These are "compiled" files, created from the actual code files. The revert operation has more to do with Deobfuscation and there are no 100% effective tool to do that for an Angular app. You will need the actual source files to modify your app.